# Polymer: running a method after a firebase-collection has been updated

Tags: firebase, polymer, polymer-1.0, firebase-polymer

**The Scenario:**

I'm currently using Polymer's "firebase-collection" element to bind data to a google chart. The user can select what items they want shown in the google chart, and upon clicking a button, the data will be updated by firebase with what was selected by the user, and built into a google chart.

**The Problem:**

The problem that I am having is that my "buildChartData" method is called before firebase updates my data property. I would like to have it called **after** the data comes back from firebase, but the only thing that I can find are "on-change" events. As such, my "buildChartData" method is being called every time the data updates, which could be well over a hundred times for a single chart.

**The Code:**

```
    <dom-module id="chart-example">
      <template>
        <style>
        ...
    </style>
    <firebase-collection id="fbColl"
      location="{{ref}}"
      data="{{dataPoints}}"
      on-data-change="buildChartData"  <!-- This is calling every time data updates-->
      ></firebase-collection>


      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{dataPoints}}">
        <p>{{item.STABBR}}</p>
      </template>
      <google-chart id="exampleChart"
                              type="{{chartType}}"
                              options="{}"
                              data="{{chartData}}" >
      </google-chart>

        <paper-button raised on-tap="buildChart">
           Build Chart 
           <iron-icon icon="arrow-forward">
           </iron-icon>
        </paper-button>

    </template>
    <script>
    (function() {
    'use strict';

    Polymer({
      is: 'chart-example',

      properties: {
        baseRef: {
          type: String,
          value: '',
          notify: true
        },
        ref: {
          type: String,
          value: '',
          notify: true
        },
        chartType: {
          type: String,
          Value: 'pie',  // for testing purposes
          notify: true
        },
        chartData: {
          type: Object,
          notify: true
        },
        firebaseNode: {
          type: String,
          value: 'rates',
          notify: true
        }
      },
      buildRef: function(baseRef) {
        return baseRef + this.firebaseNode 
      },
      buildChartData: function(e) {
        console.log(e)
        console.log(this.dataPoints)
      },
      buildChart: function() {
        this.ref = this.buildRef(this.baseRef)
        console.log(this.dataPoints)
      },
    });
  })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Use "on-firebase-value" instead, to get a snapshot value of what the firebase-collection brought back

<firebase-collection location="https://stuff.firebaseio.com/cats" data="{{events}}" on-firebase-value="_firebaseLoaded"></firebase-collection>

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you. Where did you get that answer? I was all over polymer's website, and saw no mention of on-firebase-value.Thanks again!

Comment: Same here, i eventually found it in a example from the dev summit i think or one of the codelabs, cant really remember

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `debounce()` function?

[Debounce Example](https://gist.github.com/Scarygami/a5def45785ceeeadbe10)